# Drupal: is there a marker for the cropping functionality?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there any way to add a visual marker for cropping using the cropping field in Drupal ?

(I'm using Imagefield Crop module)

Something like this: http://www.scrappintwins.com/zencart/images/large/cindy_minear_tile_overlay_s.jpg

on top of the uploaded image ready to be cropped by the dragging area.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following plugin http://devgrow.com/griddy-overlay/ to dynamically add a grid on top of any `<img>` . Using jquery selectors you can select the correct element. The plugin has many configurable options:

- rows (#, default = 10, use 0 to disable)
- rowheight (px, default = 0 [auto])
- rowgutter (px, default = 20)
- columns (#, default = 4, use 0 to disable)
- columnwidth (px, default = 0 [auto])
- columngutter (px, default = 20) color (hex, default = #ccc)
- opacity

So that you can get the grid exactly with the correct number of rows, columns and widths/heights.